# How to Convert an IEnumerable model object to single model object in view , MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ienumerable

This is not a duplicate.Though the other question is same as this it got solved when it deviated from the procedure. Here i again stumbled upon the same question.

Iam using a DB First approach.
I have a context file called Dynaportal.context.cs, which has the class called DynaPortalEntities:-

```
public partial class DynaPortalEntities : DbContext
{
   ...    
    public DbSet<Page> Pages{ get; set; }

    public DbSet<TemplateMaster> TemplateMasters { get; set; }
}
```

In view

```
@model DynaPortalMVC.Models.DynaPortalEntities
```

and in a foreach loop

```
@foreach (var item in Model.TemplateMasters)
{}
```

In the same view , I need a page model which is not iEnumerable, like this:-

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pages.Title)===========>This shows error under Title
```

So here i should convert the IEnumerable Model.Pages to a single page object to get model.pages.Title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if I understand correctly, Razor does not know what `Page` you want the title for since you are asking for the `Title` of all `Pages`.

Usually, you would loop through the `Pages` and output each title using `@foreach`.  Or, index into the `Pages`: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pages.First().Title)`.

Comment: I get error as i Type @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pages[0].) It says 'cannot apply indexing to expression type System.Data.Entity.DBSet<DynaportalMVC.Models.Page>'

Comment: Did you try `First()`? I changed my answer.  However, I doubt that using `First` or index 0 will solve your issue.  It was meant as an example of why your code is not working.